# Gradle failed to resolve dependencies

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working with Google API, so I added this script to **build.gradle** file (inside **app/** folder in my project) but I am getting errors "**failed to resolve:com.google.apis**:
please help.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.gmailquickstart"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }       
}

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev29-1.20.0' 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to have this code in your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev33-1.20.0'
}
```

reference: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1

Edit:
And as according to the reference, you could also download the jar files there to avoid referencing maven, if you wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Android is usually coded in Java. Have you tried adding the mavenCentral repository line and seeing if it gave you a different message?